# std::strstream not implementing eof and peek properly?

Tags: c++, string, stream, strstream

I have a byte data source defined like this:

```
char * data;
unsigned int dataSize;
```

`dataSize` is non zero and often quite large (megabytes)

The following code works:

```
std::string str(data, dataSize);
std::istringstream stream(str);
char firstByte = stream.peek();
```

`stream.eof()` is false, and firstByte is `1`, which is correct

The following code does not work:

```
std::strstream stream(data, dataSize);
char firstByte = stream.peek();
```

`stream.eof()` is true, and firstByte is `-1`, which is incorrect

I know that strstream is deprecated, but in this case it avoids allocating and copying twice the incoming data, which is nice. But why are peek and eof not working ?

EDIT : If I replace `std::strstream` by `std::istrstream`, this works fine. And this is OK as I'm in fact only reading from data.
But why std::strstream is not working in that case? I'm just curious.